# Setting text on Button inside Selection Listener of the same button in SWT

Tags: java, swt, jface

i have a requirement where on the selection of button i need to process some stuff and based on the result have to set the text on the same button. Below is the sample snippet.

```
    buttonOrganization = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);

    OrgSelectionBtnListener listnerButton = new OrgSelectionBtnListener( buttonOrganization, Session, false, false );
    buttonOrganization.addListener( SWT.Selection,
            listnerButton);
```

and the OrgSelectionBtnListner class is below

```
    private class OrgSelectionBtnListener  implements Listener,
PropertyChangeListener
{

public OrgSelectionBtnListener( Button orgButton, Session Session, boolean isUser, boolean isGrp )
{

}
@Override
public void propertyChange( PropertyChangeEvent evt )
{
    String propName = evt.getPropertyName();
    if( propName.equals( "OrgChanged" ) )
    {

        buttonOrganization.setText("new Group User");
    }
}

@Override
public void handleEvent( Event arg0 )
{
    buttonOrganization = ( Button ) arg0.widget;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
    {
        //Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        //@Override
        public void run()
        {               
            orgSelectionDialog.addPropertyChangeListener( OrgSelectionBtnListener.this );
        }
    } );
}

}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: your code seems correct, what problem problem or error are you experiencing?

Comment: It says **org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access** pointing to the line `buttonLoadUser.setText("Demo User");`

Comment: I think you need to show us a [mcve] showing the problem as this should not normally give invalid thread access.

Comment: Yes i will update the code. Actually i ran the above it worked fine. Will update with exact example.

Comment: `SwingUtilities` is not an appropriate class to be using with SWT code.

Comment: Actually under we are calling a class OrgSelectionDialog which is written using Swing `OrgSelectionDialog orgSelectionDialog = new OrgSelectionDialog(Session );` Any alternate suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Calling SWT from Swing is very difficult - don't do it. Calling Swing from SWT requires using the `SWT_AWT` bridge class.

Answer (score 0):

Make button variable private or final. Add selection listener by using anonymous class of Selection Listener..

```
 btn.addSelectionListener(new  SelectionListener....
```

perform your task inside method of it and setText by using

btn.setText(" ");

according to your result.